# Security of Offline Access Tokens

Tags: facebook, access-token, feed

I created an app and an offline access token so I could display a news feed on my website without requiring a Facebook login. I created two test versions in PHP and JavaScript that work fine. But I took down the JavaScript version because I was concerned about the lack of security in explicitly stating the access token in a client-side script. Is server-side the only way to go for security reasons?

Comment: You have indeed answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct to take out your access token from javascript.  As long as that access token is valid - even if it hasn't been obtained with offline_access permissions - it can be used to perform actions on behalf of that user/app/page.  All you need to make calls is the user/app/page ID which is easily obtainable and a valid access token...

I recommend you leave your access token management to your server-side scripts. Perhaps making ajax calls to refresh the posts at regular intervals...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I also developed a version in Classic ASP, using Javascript for the JSON processing and date conversion. We're migrating soon to ASP.NET, and I'll post a separate question about the migration elsewhere on the site.